# How to insert values to table based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join

I have a table called `BranchServices` and its structure as follows,

```
FkBranchId  FkServiceId SortValue
6               1           1
7               1           1
8               1           NULL
6               2           2
7               2           2
8               2           NULL
6               3           3
```

Each branch have its own Sort order (`SortValue`).Some branch haven't sort order and that branch `SortValue`s are `NULL`.When I create a new service I insert values to this table through the cross join as follows,

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices 
SELECT b.BranchId,
       s.ServiceID,
       NULL
FROM @insertedServiceID s
CROSS JOIN Branch b WHERE b.IsActive = 1
```

**But I need to change above query**.While inserting newly created service id to each branch, I need to check its current sort order. If that branch consists with `SortValue = NULL` then I need to insert `SortValue` as `Null` null  and if that branch already have Sort order need to insert  `0` to `sortValue` how to check that branch have sorting order or not before inserting newly created service. can I check it inside the cross join? so then how?

Comment: Add a left join to BranchServices and use a case expression to determine if you want 0 or NULL. Or use a correlated query like forpas did in their answer.

Comment: @SeanLange can you please provide sample answer,pls

Comment: What is wrong with the answer from forpas? Seems it would be 99% of what you need. Just use a case expression to return 0. MIN(Case when SortValue IS NOT NULL then 0 end)

Comment: @SeanLange His answer is okay for now. have one more problem, when if particular branch `sortValue` have at least one non null value, `SortValue` inserting as `0`, have any possible way to avoid this.,

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: What value do you want it to insert in that case?

Comment: @SeanLange null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the `SortValue` for the `FkBranchId` that you insert:

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices 
SELECT b.BranchId,
  s.ServiceID,
  CASE WHEN(SELECT MIN(SortValue) FROM BranchServices WHERE FkBranchId = b.BranchId) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
FROM @insertedServiceID s
CROSS JOIN Branch b WHERE b.IsActive = 1
```

I used `MIN()` to make sure that the subquery will return only 1 row (`MAX()` would also work).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one more problem, when if particular branch sortValue have at least one *non null value*, SortValue inserting as 0, have any possible way to avoid this. pls be noted this is not a problem currently ur answer is okay now, but I need to know some how occur that kind be situation how to do it

Comment: *if particular branch sortValue have at least one non null value* is there a case that the same FkBranchId  may have null and non null in SortValue? If so what do you want to insert?

Comment: Ya currently some particular branch only have all null or all non null for Sortvalue, but I need to know (for my knowledge only) how to handle if particular branch have both null and non null values I need to insert sortValue as NUll.

Comment: In that case use this case statement: `CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FROM BranchServices WHERE FkBranchId = b.BranchId AND SortValue IS NULL) THEN 0 END`

Comment: This statement will return 0 only if there are not any nulls for that FkBranchId.